# Why does Tuvok sometimes fidget with his hands?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, vulcan

Tuvok sometimes fidgets with his hands when explaining himself. As far as I recall, Vulcans don't fidget, I suppose it would look like emotional conflict.

Maybe it's some kind of routine to keep one's thoughts focused, but it really looks like normal, random fidgeting. I'm surprised he doesn't avoid it.

Edit: [Fidgeting two episodes before "Meld", at 14:17](http://dai.ly/x582nn1?start=858), [fidgeting with a Kal-Toh board, at 37:50](http://dai.ly/x568cwu?start=2270)

Comment: Everyone is different. Also, we know that Tuvok has a degenerative neurological condition from "Endgame", so maybe that is the cause.

Comment: Everyone is different, but this is so unVulcan it would be like humans picking their nose in public. Tuvok's condition is the most likely explanation. He did get palliative treatment for it, but there was no cure in the Delta quadrant.

Comment: Some humans _do_ pick their nose in public.

Comment: And surrounding people don't think too high of them.

Comment: “As far as I recall, Vulcans don't fidget, I suppose it would look like emotional conflict.” — Is that something that was mentioned in the show? I don’t think Vulcans are particularly worried about what things look like.

Comment: He's pinching his hands in a fit of energy. They call it the Vulcan Nervous Pinch

Comment: I don't see any fidgeting with the Kal-Toh board, and the first bit of "fidgeting" looks like he has his hands folded up much the way they would be when he's meditating. Might just do it when he's trying to think.

Comment: Unfortunately the clip is cropped. The original shows his hands on his lap, holding the board on his lap, randomly fidgeting with it.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this could easily be explained as an early indicator of Tuvok's neurodegenerative disease. One could also blame side effects of the memory virus from "Flashback." There is also the fact that Tuvok's studies of various Alpha Quadrant martial arts, archery, and Starfleet combat experience give him different tendencies than the more science and diplomacy focused Vulcans we've seen throughout the show.

Regardless, the most likely cause is that Tim Russ fidgets. Though the other two actors playing Tuvok over the years have had small parts, neither LeRoy D. Brazile nor Demetris Lawson showed a single sign of fidgeting.